# Construct theory with a condition

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I would need some help here. I'm preparing for finals from mathematical logic and as I am browsing through some exercises, I often found these types:

Let's say we have 2 propositions $\phi$ and $\psi$:

**a,** construct a theory $T$ which is unsatisfiable if $\phi \vDash \psi$

**b,** using Skolemisation find the theory $T$ which is unsatisfiable if $\phi \vDash \psi$

I would like to get some thoughts about how to approach problems like these. Also, an example with solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $\phi \vDash \psi$, then the theory $T = \{ \phi \land \lnot \psi \}$ is *unsatisfiable*.

Comment: This was easy. My bad. Thanks :)

Comment: Part (b) is puzzling, there is no such thing as **the** theory. As to Skolemizing $\phi \land \lnot \psi$, one cannot do it explicitly without a description of $\phi$and $\psi$.